# Куда круче - значение

Tags: значения

> Я первый раз в жизни удивил Бутова и это бы я запомнил навсегда. Это стало бы главным событием моей жизни, про меня рассказывали бы легенды, но последующие события были **куда круче**.

(В. Березин, *Путевые знаки*)

Что значит *куда круче*?

/edit: Как получилось, что у слова *куда* появилось такое странное значение?

Comment: Здесь `куда` == `куда как` == `намного`

Comment: using the same informal language, it means "a lot cooler"

Comment: In English we say "way cooler"—It's basically the same in my opinion. 



Куда = where
Way = a direction, path, etc = "where" 

или как-то так ))

Comment: Откуда значение появилось - не знаю, я не лингвист. Но оно упомянуто на wiki https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эпитетом «крутой» традиционно переводится английское (а также немецкое и
французское) «cool» (досл. «прохладный»), означающее «спокойный», «уравновешенный», «хладнокровный», «бесстрастный». Английское «Cool!» — практически полный аналог нашего «Круто!» и так же, imho, не имеет ни малейшего негативного подтекста.

6. В разговорной речи крутым называют человека, который многого добился в жизни, имеет хороший заработок, престижную работу, большие связи, власть и т. п.
   Крутые парни. |

сущ.
В этой тихой камерной обстановке отдыхают крутые — те, у которых на лице написано: «Жизнь удалась».

7. Действия, решения и т. п. называют крутыми, если они строгие, решительные.
   Предпринять крутые меры. |

нар.
С незаконными эмигрантами в этой стране обходятся весьма круто: их немедленно высылают за пределы государства.

8. Крутым в разговоре вы называете что-либо очень модное, привлекательное, то, что вызывает у вас восхищение, одобрение.
   У него крутой мобильник. | На ней был надет крутой костюм из красной кожи. |

нар.
Музыканты очень круто играли.

9. Рестораны, клубы и т. п. в разговорной речи называют крутыми, если они достаточно дорогие и там собираются известные люди, например певцы, музыканты и т. п.
   Её часто видят в крутом ресторане в гостинице «Рэдиссон-Славянская».
10. Вы используете в разговорной речи восклицание Круто!, когда одобряете что-либо, выражаете своё удовольствие или восхищение этим.
    Каникулы в Англии — это круто!

Answer (score 2):

It means that events later were much more colorful and exciting (to be remembered) than before.

Answer (score 2):

In present days "круто" mostly means "great". It should not be translated as "cool" except in places where both "great" and "cool" are appropriate.

But the original meaning goes like this:

```
"крутой" - "tough guy"
"крутые меры" - "strong measures".
"куда круче" ~ more harsh than expected/previously was.
```

Answer (score 2):

"курто" until it recently became widely used as counterpart to "cool" was used as "very rough".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMP3qQR4EFA

Answer (score 1):

It means in Russian language something like 'much cooler'.

Comment: It means "rougher", not "cooler" in this context.

Comment: `more tough` I'd say

Answer (score 1):

"More impressive", in perhaps a controversial way.

Answer (score 1):

"Куда круче" означает "way more awesome". "Круче" - это сравнительная форма от "крутой", то есть "awesome". "Куда", как и "way", используется для усиления значения. Как у слова "way" могло появиться такое странное значение?

К слову, выражение разговорное.